# Matching value to closest value range with minimal complexity

Tags: java, search, time, range

I encountered a problem which I need some help with - suppose I have some data set consisting of keys (integers) and values (integers as well). I need to be able to, given some value of a key, find the minimal key range to which it belongs (that is, find the closest greater and smaller keys) and then return the matching value via interpolation. I was wondering which way would allow me to do this in the fastest time (space complexity matters much less). also, deletion is irrelevant and all values are given at startup (we may assume there will be no more values added after startup). My emphasis is on search time, rather than insertion.

The most basic solution would be to keep a sorted array of keys and use binary search on it - until either I find the input key or find two adjacent elements which are greater and smaller than the input key. This option would take O(log n) for insertion and searching. I was wondering if there is any better.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a NavigableMap such as TreeMap.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put(1, 10);
map.put(0, -10);
map.put(5, 25);
map.put(3, 20);

// find the value below.
int key = 2;
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry1 = map.floorEntry(key);
Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry2 = map.ceilingEntry(key);
System.out.println(key + " is between " + entry1 + " and " + entry2);
```

prints

```
2 is between 1=10 and 3=20
```

Inserts, updates, lookups and deletes have a time complexity of `O(log N)`